# Documentation on initialization sequence of EmberJS router?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

Can anyone throw some light on the initialization sequence when EmberJS router is used http://emberjs.com/guides/outlets/

In this Controller create is not called explicitly, when is the data for each controller fetched from the Rails server. Is it only when the corresponding connectOutlet is invoked ?

If there is any better documentation available ?

Comment: Head to http://trek.github.com/

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcdZFA5CMCk), a talk that covers emberjs booting.

Comment: Also looked into details on Ember Objects at http://www.cerebris.com/blog/2012/03/06/understanding-ember-object/ its a good read. Though its not about booting.